# tailwind transition from grayscale to color not working in darkmode

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have the following styling on image icons. My intention is to apply a grayscale filter and transition to color on hover. But only in dark mode. If I remove the dark: from the transition works in dark and light mode. However light mode we want to just show the color images. So I thought I could just add the dark: prefix and it would do that.

However, it applies the grayscale filter; but not the transition.

```
w-full h-full object-contain dark:transition dark:duration-400 dark:ease-in-out dark:grayscale hover:grayscale-0
```

Is there a way to fix this or am I running into a bug?